# TIB access in Win32

Tags: c, windows, winapi, x86, memory-segmentation

Digging into the implementation of Win32 API functions that work with TIB (Thread Information Block), such as:

- TLS access functions: `TlsAlloc`, `TlsFree`, `TlsSetValue`, `TlsGetValue`
- `GetLastError`, `SetLastError`
- messaging subsystem: `GetMessage`, `PeekMessage` and etc.

one finds out that all of them access the TIB, sometimes called TEB (Thread Environment Block), by reading the contents of the `fs:[0x18]` selector.

OTOH this is unnecessary, since the `fs` register **directly** points to it. According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) and what I see in practice, the `fs` register holds the address to the beginning of the TIB structure, whereas at offset 0x18 it has a pointer to itself.

What could be the reason to access the TIB indirectly nevertheless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any instruction using `FS` requires an override, which adds a byte to the instruction (and generally requires assembly language to use it at all). The pointer at `FS:18` is (at least if memory serves correctly) based off of `DS` instead, so it can be used without an override, saving a byte when it's used and (most importantly for many people) can be used directly from a higher level language such as C or C++ instead of requiring assembly language.

Comment: most compilers these days have intrinsics for accessing FS/GS segments (see `__readfs*`/`__readgs*` on MSVC), so the last point isn't so applicable these days.

Comment: So, you say that TIB contains a pointer to itself as a member is to allow a shorter instruction and for higher level languages? Sounds very weird...